# MongoDB slow compares to Oracle DB

Tags: mongodb

I have a table of 20 million rows in Oracle and same in MongoDB.

When I run in Oracle

```
select count(*) from PAX where STAY_PERIOD > 30;
```

I get the results in 50 seconds.

While in MongoDB

```
db.PAX.find( {STAY_PERIOD: { $gt: 30 } }).count();
```

it takes 120 seconds.

Is that the norms ? What can be missing here, and how to check for the slow performance behind MongoDB.

Thanks

Comment: do you have an index on the field `STAY_PERIOD` in mongodb?
please share the explain result of MongoDB query , execute the following : `db.PAX.find( {STAY_PERIOD: { $gt: 30 } }).count().explain();`

Comment: I think the proper command would be `db.PAX.countDocuments({STAY_PERIOD: { $gt: 30 } })` Your command would correspond with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select * from PAX where STAY_PERIOD > 30);` - However, the optimizer would transform back to given SQL.

Comment: @Moussab: No indexes are involved here. I want to see with full table scan which environment will do better.

Comment: @Wernfries: will try the query and share the results.

Comment: @Wernfries: same results. It is slow.